# Post call in iOS with Webservice implementation in JAVA

Tags: java, ios, web-services, post

I'm stuck with this problem. Hope you can help.

I have implemented webservices in Java and consumed the webservice in iOS with GET method without any issue. However I have not been able to get the POST methods working.

Are there any way I can check that the server implementation is correct? Entering the URL in a browser does not give any call to the POST method. What migt be wrong in the methods below?

This is my server implmentation:

```
@Path("/v1/consumer/")
public class V1_consumer {


@POST
@Path("/updateConsumptionMetric")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response updateConsumptionMetric(String incomingData) throws Exception {
    String returnString = null;
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    DBC dBC = new DBC();

    try{
        JSONObject partsData = new JSONObject(incomingData);
        System.out.println("jsonData: " + partsData.toString());

        int http_code = dBC.updateConsumptionMetricForConsumer(partsData.optInt("ConsumerID"), partsData.optInt("ConsumptionMetric"));
        if(http_code == 200){
            jsonObject.put("HTTP_CODE", "200");
            jsonObject.put("MSG", "Items has been entered successfully");
            returnString = jsonArray.put(jsonObject).toString();
        }else{
            return Response.status(500).entity("Unable to process items").build();
        } 
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(500).entity("Server was not able to process your request").build();
    }
    return Response.ok(returnString).build();
}
```

and this is my iOS implementation:

```
-(void)updateConsumptionMetric:(NSNumber*)metricID forConsumer:(NSNumber*)consumerID{
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:consumerID, @"ConsumerID", metricID, @"ConsumptionMetric", nil];

NSData * JsonData =[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString * jsonString= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://profolo.ddns.net:8080/com.profolo.it.cdss.api/api/v1/consumer/updateConsumptionMetric"]]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request
                                   queue: queue
                       completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if (error || !data) {
                               // Handle the error

                               NSLog(@"Server Error : %@", error);
                           } else {
                               // Handle the success

                               NSLog(@"Server Response :%@",response);
                           }
                       }
 ];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that entering the URL to browser always makes a GET request, not POST request to the webservice. So, I suggest that you should use another tool to make POST request (I recommend using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)).

One more thing, you should change this line of code

```
public Response updateConsumptionMetric(String incomingData)
```

to

```
public Response updateConsumptionMetric(@RequestBody String incomingData)
```

Comment: Thanks Tuan, By using Postman i solved the issue in the Java code and finally I found an error in the iOS code as well. The row [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; was missing.